# Limiting GHC's memory usage

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is there a way to limit ghc's memory usage during compilation, without compromising code quality? I am on a 2GB machine, and it literally halts during builds. GHC version 7.10.3, Ubuntu 14.04, 4GB swap.

Answer (score 1):

one way would be to use containers with memory limits. I'm currently testing this theory, and it works but you'll have a major downside as the limit you're setting for the memory will cause GHC to just allocate swap space. it will take ages.

it would probably be a good idea to look a [this solution](http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/Building-on-limited-memory-environments-or-does-M-really-work-td5866310.html) too. I'm quoting :

> -j just tells GHC to parallelise compilation across modules. This can 
>       increase the maximum heap size needed by the compiler.
>
> -A sets the nursery size; to first order the doesn't affect the 
>       maximum heap size, but rather is helpful when running parallel 
>       programs (e.g. ghc with -j) to minimize the frequency with which we 
>       must garbage-collect.
>
> -M is a bit tricky to define. For one, it defines the maximum heap 
>      size beyond which we will terminate. However, we also use it in 
>      garbage collector to make various decisions about GC scheduling. I'll 
>      admit that I'm not terribly familiar with the details here.